# how can I add my product2 in my cart using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code and I cant add another product to my cart, it only works to my product 1. My css and html are all basic and I dont know what syntax I must use, I try this code Myfunction(item) method where the id of each product will store in the item, the problem is I can only add product one time.

```
   <head>
    <style>
.container{
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}

#cart{
    left: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class ="container">
    <div id ="products">
    <h1>Product 1</h1>
</div>
<button id="Add">Add</button>

<div id ="products">
    <h1>Product 2</h1>
</div>
<button id="Add">Add</button>

</div>




<div id="cart">
<h1>Cart</h1>
</div>


<input type="submit" id="sub">

<input type="text" id="texts">




    <script>

var Add = document.getElementById("Add");
var product = document.getElementById("products");
var cart = document.getElementById("cart");
var sub = document.getElementById("sub");


sub.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    var texts = document.getElementById("texts").value;

var text = document.createElement("p");




text.innerHTML = texts;
cart.appendChild(text);



})














Add.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    
    var clone = product.cloneNode(true);
    var dup = cart.appendChild(clone);
})



        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide html?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I put my css and html here sorry for beig late, I hope you can help me, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define same id on multiple elements.

`getElementById` can only get one element.

You can change products to class, and add `click` event linstener to each `Add` button, then find the parent element and clone it, delete `Add` button from clone and add it to the cart.

```js
const products = document.getElementsByClassName('products')
const Add = document.getElementsByClassName('Add')
const cart = document.getElementById("cart");
const sub = document.getElementById("sub");
sub.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var texts = document.getElementById("texts").value;
  var text = document.createElement("p");
  text.innerHTML = texts;
  cart.appendChild(text);
})
Array.prototype.forEach.call(Add, (a) => a.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let clone = e.target.parentElement.cloneNode(true)
  clone.getElementsByClassName('Add')[0].remove()
  cart.appendChild(clone)
}))
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

#cart {
  left: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="products">
    <h1>Product 1</h1>
    <button class="Add">Add</button>
  </div>
  <div class="products">
    <h1>Product 2</h1>
    <button class="Add">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="cart">
  <h1>Cart</h1>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="sub">
<input type="text" id="texts">
```